# Show that the ideal $I = 3\mathbb Z[x] + (x^3-x^2+2x-1)\mathbb Z[x]$ is not a principal ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Show that the ideal $I = 3\mathbb Z[x] + (x^3-x^2+2x-1)\mathbb Z[x]$ is not a principal ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$

**Intuition:** Assume that $$3\mathbb Z[x] + (x^3-x^2+2x-1)\mathbb Z[x]=<p(x)>$$ for  $p(x) \in Z[x]$

So$$3\mathbb Z[x] + (x^3-x^2+2x-1)\mathbb Z[x]=p(x)Z[x]$$

Since $3\in p(x)Z[x]$ $$3=p(x)q(x) $$ where $q(x)\in Z[x]$

Which implies $p(x)=-3,-1,1$ or $3$. Since this is a contradiction $$3\mathbb Z[x] + (x^3-x^2+2x-1)\mathbb Z[x]\ne<p(x)>$$ for any $p(x)\in Z[x]$

Comment: Its generator would have to divide both $3$ and $x^3-x^2+2x-1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thus maybe I can write in the beginning of the intuition $<3,X^3-X^2+2X+1>=<p(x)>$? and solve it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is pretty much a proof already; indeed if the ideal is principal then its generator must divide $3$, hence it must be one of $\{-3,-1,1,3\}$. Clearly $\pm3$ does not divide $x^3-x^2+2x-1$ and to show that it cannot be generated by $\pm1$ it suffices to show that the ideal is not the entire ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you assist me in Would with that one: **Show that** $$\mathbb Z[x] / I \cong \overline{\mathbb Z}[x]/ \overline{I}$$
**Where** 

$$\overline{\mathbb Z} = (\mathbb Z /3 \mathbb Z), \overline{I} = the \space ideal \space generated \space by \space the \space polynomial \space x^3 -x^2+2x-1 \space over \space \mathbb Z /3 \mathbb Z$$. and Is $\mathbb Z[x] / I$ a field?and will its order be $3$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291898/show-mathbb-zx-i-cong-overline-mathbb-zx-overlinei-where-over?noredirect=1#comment6770878_3291898

Comment: That seems like a whole new question, but to be brief, yes indeed
$$\mathbb Z[x] / I \cong \overline{\mathbb Z}[x]/ \overline{I}.$$
The order of this quotient is $3^3=27$, because its elements are (represented by) polynomials of degree less than $3$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$. The quotient is a field because the polynomial is irreducible over  $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: So how do we show that the ideal $I \ne Z[x]$?